# Calling PL/SQL procedure from SoapUi with Groovy

Tags: oracle, groovy, plsql, soapui

I'm trying to call PL/SQL procedure from SoapUi with Groovy and I get error like: "..that function does not exist" I guess that this part of code is for calling PL/SQL functions, and when I check it with PL/SQL function - it works. Could anyone help with solution for calling PL/SQL procedure with Groovy?

Sample of code that works for calling PL/SQL Function:

```
 sql.call("{? = call IFSUI_SG_CA_TEST_UTILS.getCustomerAccountData(?, ?, ?)}", [Sql.VARCHAR, customerNo, accountNo, accountIbanNo]) { result ->
 log.info (results);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally finded it, here is example of calling PL/SQL procedure from Groovy with also IN OUT parameter, I hope that it will save time someone :)

With IN parameter:

```
 sql.call("{call IFSUI_SG_CA_TEST_UTILS.getCustomerAccountData(?,?,?)}",
 [customerNo,accountNo,accountIbanNo])
```

customerNo,... are variables

With IN OUT parameter:

> ```
> sql.call("{call IFSUI_SG_CA_TEST_UTILS.getCustomerAccountData(?,?,?)}",
> [Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(customerNo)), Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(accountNo)), 
> Sql.inout(Sql.VARCHAR(accountIbanNo))])
> ```